# How to integrate many CSS files

Tags: css

What is the best way to integrate many CSS files to one integrated CSS file as global CSS?

We can supposed that every page has own CSS selectors with attributes.
If we simply copy and paste all css files into one file, the problem is that a.html will call b.html, c.html, d.html, ...., z.html css selectors and attributes even the page doesn't need call other CSS styles.

Is there any solution??

Comment: Why put them all in one file if none of the CSS crosses over to the other pages?

Comment: So, I don't need to care about the number of css files? Each css file has approximately less than 100 lines. A few file has only less than 5 lines. If I use @import, anyway I have to keep those files and it will affect page rendering time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caution when use @import, it increases the load time. New researches show that it's better to have ONE big css file than SIX small.

Problem with @import is, the download of the second file may start only when the first has been downloaded, which may cause glitches.

You can create a big file and use a compressor, like http://gpbmike.github.io/refresh-sf/

Of course, save it as style.min.css, let's say, and keep a backup of your style.css ;)

Take a look here too: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

Comment: If I create only one global file, then I'm supposed to use less to compile. I really agree with your load-time issue. The problem is how to call only styles the page needs.

Comment: Right. How many files do you have? If the styles will be used in another page or pages, then this way they will be already cached later.

Comment: there are main CSS file and 10 CSS files for sub-pages. I wanted to combine all of them into one file. In this case, how do I use Cache of each sub-page?

Comment: You can just paste sub contents into the main css. they probably aren't big as the main file, and you should comment each section to separate them.

Comment: Also, take a look in this Smashing Magazine article: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/18/7-principles-of-clean-and-optimized-css-code/

Answer (score 0):

use `@import` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import

master.css

```
@import 'a.css';
@import 'c.css';
```

a.css

```
el { style : lalala; }
```

b.css

```
el2 { style : lalala; }
```